# IF/ELSE conditions on Spark / JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
for (java.util.Iterator<Row> iter = dataframe1.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Row it = (iter.next());
    String item = it.get(2).toString();
    String rayon = it.get(6).toString();
    Double d = Double.parseDouble(rayon)/100000;
    String geomType = it.get(14).toString();
    Dataset<Row> res_f = null;

    if(geomType.equalsIgnoreCase("Polygon")) {
        res_f= dataframe2.withColumn("ST_WITHIN",expr("ST_WITHIN(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,')',4326)),ST_GeomFromWKT('"+item+"'))"));

    } else {
        res_f = dataframe2.withColumn("ST_BUFFERR",expr("ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromWKT('"+item+"'),"+d+")")).withColumn("ST_WITHIN",expr("ST_WITHIN(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,')',4326)),ST_BUFFERR)"));

    }
    res_f.show();
 }
```

But `res_f` returns nothing and is always null.

I'm using `Spark` with `Java`.

**EDIT**

**I solved the problem**, just change this line from `Dataset<Row> res_f = null;` to `Dataset<Row> res_f;`

I need your help .

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? It seems that the geomType is never equals to Polygon

Comment: No , geomType is equals to Polygon